# GSuite DNS Records + Firebase DNS Records: Which goes in first?

Tags: firebase, cloudflare

So I have recently purchased a domain, I caved and bought one email with @domain.io

GSuite **requires** their verification TXT records to be added **first**, so that means no other records can be existing in Cloudflare, they also **require** that file to not be deleted

Firebase also **requires** their verification TXT records to be added **first**

What am I supposed to do here? Am I missing something?

I tried adding Firebase's verification TXT record around two days ago and it still can't verify it.

Comment: I'm in Google Domains trying to add Firebase's email records right now. I a record already in use error when I attempt to add the TXT record corresponding to SPF. I looked at the synthetic records for GSuite, which also has the same type of TXT SPF record. I have a feeling there is a syntax that will allow the two to be combined, but I don't know what it is yet.

Comment: I think I found it here: https://mxtoolbox.com/problem/spf/txt-record . I am going to try manually combining this record, since the others I have been asked to add (so far) don't seem like they conflict.